# Просмотр djvu и pdf файлов без использования стороннего ПО

Tags: delphi, pdf

Подскажите компоненты для просмотра djvu и pdf файлов. Для PDF есть много компонентов, а вот для djvu не нашел. Есть libdjvulibre.dll, но описание методов не нашел.  ActiveX, установку плагинов для TWebBrower не предлагать

Answer (score 1):

Для DejaVu ничего нативного для Delphi нет. Либо сами занимаетесь переводом имеющихся C/C++ вариантов (в правильности некоторых я не уверен), либо по документации создаёте свою, либо, как другие, пользуете ActiveX/Browser плагины. Правило "неуловимого Джо".
Для PDF же куча вариантов, даже среди бесплатных, в зависимости от того, насколько глубоко вы хотите работать со стандартом.

Comment: А есть примеры работы с плагинами? Т.е. я имею ввиду, что если плагин - это одна или несколько dll, то пример работы с dll напрямую с ее экспортными функциями с отображением, например, на TPanel. И ActiveX предусматривает, что у конечного пользователя уже установлена программа, что не есть гуд

Comment: Через TBrowser и установкой плагина у пользователя есть: http://www.delphisources.ru/forum/showthread.php?t=20679   Так, как вы просите, т.е. предоставить "обертку" для DLL - нет, но вы можете скачать SDK для C++ (http://djvu.com/download/ - триальная версия!) и попытаться разобраться самому.

Comment: Интересует именно "обертка", а такой вариант я делал, не понравилось. В итоге решил остановиться на следующем варианте. Запускаю  SumatraPDF через ShellExecute и "натягиваю" на Panel. Устанавливать/регистрировать ничего не нужно, быстро и минимум кода)

Answer (score 0):

для PDF можно использовать Adobe Reader ActiveX. если Adobe Reader установлен конечно. причём можно даже встроить отображение PDF посредством Adobe Reader ActiveX в своё окно.

Answer (score 0):

Итого, "оберток" готовых для популярных библиотек для просмотра файлов pdf и djvu я не нашел. Устанавливать ActiveX компоненты  - это самый простой способ для работы и для большинства случаем является оптимальным, но иногда требуется запускать только портативную версию. Для этого случая предлагаю просматривать документы, используя SumatraPDF. (подсмотрел решение на http://www.sql.ru/forum/881691/pdf-viewer-for-delphi-1-0 от Gator) + своих пару строк кода.

Объявил несколько процедур:

```
 procedure TDataM.SetToPanel(const WND: THandle; var Panel: TPanel);
    begin
      if (WND = 0) or (Panel = nil) then Exit;
      Winapi.Windows.SetParent(WND, Panel.Handle);

      SetWindowLong(WND, GWL_STYLE, $56000000);  // STYLE like Panel
      SetWindowLong(WND, GWL_EXSTYLE, $00010200);

      SetWindowPos(WND, HWND_TOP, Panel.ClientRect.Left, Panel.ClientRect.Top, Panel.ClientRect.Right, Panel.ClientRect.Bottom, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
      Panel.Tag := WND;
    end;

    function TDataM.StartApp(App: String): TProcessInformation;
    var si: TStartupInfo;
        sa: TSecurityAttributes;
    begin

      GetStartupInfo(si);
      FillChar(si, SizeOf(si), #0);
      si.cb := SizeOf(si);
      si.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
      si.wShowWindow := 0 ;//SW_HIDE; //SW_SHOWNORMAL;
      FillChar(sa, SizeOf(sa), #0);
      sa.nLength := SizeOf(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
      sa.bInheritHandle := true;
      sa.lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;
      if not CreateProcess(nil,                 // Module Name Pointer
                           PWideChar(App),      // Command Line Pointer
                           nil,                 // Process Security Attributes Pointer
                           nil,                 // Thread Security Attributes Pointer
                           true,                // Inheritance Flag
                           CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE or NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, //Creation Flags
                           nil,                 // Environment Block Pointer
                           nil,                 // Current Directory Pointer
                           si,
                           Result) then
       RaiseLastOSError
       else
       WaitForInputIdle(Result.hProcess, INFINITE);
    end;

    function ShowHandleFromPID(hwnd: THandle; AData: pointer):BOOL; stdcall;
    var pid:DWORD;
    begin
      Result:=true;
      GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, pid);
      if pid = DWORD(AData) then
         if (GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HWNDPARENT) = 0) and
         // (IsWindowVisible( hwnd ) or IsIconic(hwnd)) //and
          ((GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) {and WS_EX_APPWINDOW}) <> 0) then
          SumatraHandle:= hwnd;
    end;

    function TDataM.ViewApp(const AFile: string; var Panel: TPanel): TProcessInformation;
    begin
      Result := StartApp(Sumatra + ' "' + AFile + '"');

      EnumWindows(@ShowHandleFromPID, Result.dwProcessId);
      Panel.Tag:= SumatraHandle;
    if Panel.Tag = 0 then
//      showmessage('Процесс не найден')
    else
      SetToPanel(Panel.Tag, Panel);
        SetToPanel(Panel.Tag, Panel);
    end;

    procedure TDataM.AlignToPanel(const WND: THandle; var Panel: TPanel);
    begin
      if (WND = 0) or (Panel = nil) then Exit;
      SetWindowPos(WND, HWND_TOP, Panel.ClientRect.Left, Panel.ClientRect.Top, Panel.ClientRect.Right, Panel.ClientRect.Bottom, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    end;


    var
    viewInfo: TProcessInformation; //глобальная переменная
    Sumatra : string; //путь к exe
    SumatraHandle: THandle; //результат выполнения ShowHandleFromPID
```

При создании формы

```
    viewInfo.hProcess:= 0;
```

При открытии файла

```
    procedure TForm1.ViewBook(AFile: string);
    begin
      if viewInfo.hProcess <> 0 then
      begin
        if TerminateProcess(viewInfo.hProcess, NO_ERROR) then
        begin 
          CloseHandle(viewInfo.hThread); // закрываем дескриптор процесса
          CloseHandle(viewInfo.hProcess); // закрываем дескриптор потока
        end;
      end;

      viewInfo:= DataM.ViewApp(AFile, Viewer);
    end;
```

Comment: SumatraPDF использует DjVuLibre и MuPDF, т.е. это тоже всего лишь обёртка.

Comment: да я и не против, ведь свою обертку писать времени и желания нет